# Handle multiple elements with the same selector with nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I'm using `nightwatch-cucumber` with the use of `PageObjects` to automate tests. `nightwatch-cucumber` based on `nightwatch.js`. So, I'm completely new to JavaScript. So far, I prefered using Java as language for Selenium/WebDriver automation.

I want to edit multiple input fields with defined values. The problem is that all these input fields have the same selector. And the number of the input fields is not known at the beginning of a test or is different from test to test. So, I need a solution. In the "holy" java world I can do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = webdriver.getElements('input.myclass');
for (WebElement el : listOfElements) {
    el.sendKeys("abc");
}
```

In JavaScript it's a little bit tricky and I don't know to handle with. In my `PageObject` I tried the following:

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{
    test() {
      this.api.elements('css selector', 'input.myclass',function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
          console.log(result.value[i].ELEMENT);
          this.api.elementIdValue(result.value[i].ELEMENT, 'abc');
        }
      });

      this.api.pause(3000);
      return this.api;
    }
  }]
};
```

But this worked not for me. In this case I get an error while test execution (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementIdValue' of undefined`). Also, I don't want to handle everything in asynchronous callback function, because the following test steps maybe require the completed handling on the multiple input fields.

So, how can I implement such a solution to handle multiple elements in `nightwatch-cucumber` with and without callback functions? And what do you prefer in that case?

Comment: There's no way to avoid the callback since all the commands are executed asynchronously. As for the error, it is due to the context of `this` which holds a different reference in the callback provided to `this.api.elements`.

Answer (score 4):

thx to @Florent B.

I answered my own question. The following code works for me now:

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{
    test() {
      this.api.elements('css selector', 'input.myclass',function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
          this.elementIdValue(result.value[i].ELEMENT, 'abc');
        }
      });

      return this.api;
    }
  }]
};
```

Because the code inside the callback function runs asynchronous I think you have to wait for a special condition (e.g. with `waitForElementVisible`) to go on with the automated test. Because sometimes you have to for the successful completed callback function before keep going with next steps in automated tests.